# Monitor Preferences > Monitor: Unknown

Tags: monitor

```
root@tarvid-laptop:~# ddcprobe
vbe: VESA 3.0 detected.
oem: Intel(r)Cantiga Graphics Chip Accelerated VGA BIOS
vendor: Intel Corporation
product: Intel(r)Cantiga Graphics Controller Hardware Version 0.0
memory: 65472kb
mode: 1280x1024x256
mode: 1280x1024x64k
mode: 1280x1024x16m
mode: 1024x768x256
mode: 1024x768x64k
mode: 1024x768x16m
mode: 640x480x16m
mode: 800x600x64k
mode: 800x600x16m
mode: 640x480x256
mode: 800x600x256
mode: 640x480x64k
edid: 
edid: 1 3
id: 2201
eisa: SPT2201
serial: 00000ba2
manufacture: 37 2007
input: sync on green, analog signal.
screensize: 47 30
gamma: 2.200000
dpms: RGB, active off, no suspend, no standby
timing: 720x400@70 Hz (VGA 640x400, IBM)
timing: 720x400@88 Hz (XGA2)
timing: 640x480@60 Hz (VGA)
timing: 640x480@67 Hz (Mac II, Apple)
timing: 640x480@72 Hz (VESA)
timing: 640x480@75 Hz (VESA)
timing: 800x600@60 Hz (VESA)
timing: 800x600@72 Hz (VESA)
timing: 800x600@75 Hz (VESA)
timing: 832x624@75 Hz (Mac II)
timing: 1024x768@87 Hz Interlaced (8514A)
timing: 1024x768@70 Hz (VESA)
timing: 1024x768@75 Hz (VESA)
timing: 1280x1024@75 (VESA)
ctiming: 1152x864@60
ctiming: 1280x800@60
ctiming: 1280x1280@60
ctiming: 1280x960@60
ctiming: 1280x1024@60
ctiming: 1360x850@60
ctiming: 1440x1440@60
ctiming: 1680x1680@60
dtiming: 1920x1080@69
monitorrange: 15-94, 24-77
monitorname: Sceptre
monitorname: X22WG-1080P
```

Comment: yeah..it happens a lot my 15" monitor is detected (acer) and my 26" isn't (samsung) though, if i change the video cable..VGA,HDMIDVI etc... sometimes it gets recognized

Comment: what is the mechanism which recognizes monitors?  Surely they must be interrogated to find available settings through a utility.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when i updated to 11.04 beta.
I have a 22'' Samsung monitor which was detected correctly up unti 10.10.

My problem was solved by creating an xorg.conf file manually:

`sudo Xorg -configure`

When i rebooted, the monitor was detected fine.